# Translate SSH terminal input to X.org's?

Tags: linux, ssh, keyboard, xorg, remote-control

I just had an idea that it would be nice to ssh on to my PC using my mobile phone and remote-control the keyboard by writing to the terminal, using arrow keys etc. A sample use case would be scrolling down a Firefox page or pressing space to pause playback in my media player without having a program written specifically for my application. Is there such a utility already around?

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called VNC that is designed to do exactly this although it may log into a new X Session rather then using your existing one so you may not have access to applications that are currently open on your computer, I didn't spend much time working around this but there is a existing question on server fault https://serverfault.com/questions/27044/how-to-vnc-into-an-existing-x-session.

You will need to install and run a VNC server on your computer and a VNC client many are available search vnc in the play store, there are also plenty of howto's on google.